# df.to_excel capture only last request of iteration pandas

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to iterate through a large dataset and using to.excel() to write in my dataframe to Excel.

My code:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'report.xlsx')
for x in range(3):
   slq = ("select date_added, fruit_id from market")
   data = pd.read_sql(sql, c)
   df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   df.to_excel(writer)
   writer.save()
```

When this is run, I am only capturing the 3rd request in my range. Is there a different method that would allow me to capture all 3 requests in my range?

Comment: You are overwriting the file on each `writer.save()`. Do you want three files? Do you want to append on each write?

Comment: @kyle I want to append on each and write. So one file should include all 3 writes. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a `ExcelWriter.append` method. Instead, make a list of the dataframes and `pd.concat` at the end.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'report.xlsx')
dfs = []

for x in range(3):
    sql = ("select date_added, fruit_id from market")
    data = pd.read_sql(sql, c)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    dfs.append(df)
    
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.to_excel(writer)
writer.save()
```

Alternatively, `pd.DataFrame.to_excel` does have a `startrow` argument that could be used to append.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'report.xlsx')
row = 0
for x in range(3):
    sql = ("select date_added, fruit_id from market")
    data = pd.read_sql(sql, c)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_excel(writer, startrow=row)
    row += len(df)
    
writer.save()
```